# Reduce font size and space of TOC Title in Latex

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I have created a LaTex document. The problems are:

1. The abstract title is too big.
2. The space before it needs to be reduced.

[image]

I tried using:  `\vspace{-2cm}` or `\vspace{2p}` but it didn't work.

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: i used report document ...

   \documentclass[12pt]{report}

Comment: I already got the answer for my question here

http://www.noktec.be/archives/849